# Function output stores in python dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am calling a function and convert the output into json. For each function output data comes under square bracket but i don't want separate square bracket. Every function output should come under single square bracket.

Tried below code for calling function:

```
    jsondata = {}
    df_data = input_data_merge()
    jsdf = df_data.to_json(orient="records")
    jsondata["Input"] = json.loads(jsdf)

    jsondata['Output'] = count_matrix_dct
   
    jsdf1 = merged_df.to_json(orient="records")
    jsondata["Mismatch"] = json.loads(jsdf1)
    df_final_str = (json.dumps(jsondata))

    return df_final_str
```

Output:

```
{
    "Input": [
        {
         "src_table_name": "Table A",
        "src_column_name": "EMP",
        "src_business_key_name": "ID",
        "src_select_column_names": "NAME,SALARY,LASTNAME",
        "src_where_condition": "1=1",
        "src_schema_name": "testdb"
        }
    ],
    "Output": {
        "match_data": 1,
        "mismatch_data": 0,
        "missing_data": 0,
        "extra": 0
    },
    "Mismatch": []
}
```

Expected output:

```
[{
  "OutputArray": [
    {
      "Input": {
        "src_table_name": "Table A",
        "src_column_name": "EMP",
        "src_business_key_name": "ID",
        "src_select_column_names": "NAME,SALARY,LASTNAME",
        "src_where_condition": "1=1",
        "src_schema_name": "testdb"
        
      },
      "Output": {
        "match_data": 1,
        "mismatch_data": 0,
        "missing_data": 0,
        "extra": 0
      },
      "Mismatch": {

      },

    }
  ]
}]
```

Please suggest how can i achieve this?

Comment: What are the extra empty dictionaries in your expected output for? Are they intentional?

Comment: extra empty dictionaries is second output, thrid output and so on . Currently i have give one input and generating the output. that's my assumption currently.

Comment: @Jab - have removed extra empty dictionaries.